# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Когда после загрузки сохраняю через функцию, то происходит вышеуказанная ошибка.

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Но когда сохраняю без функции, то всё работает.

```
1, 2, 3, 2
```

Почему так?

```
import json
import os

filename = fr"{os.environ['userprofile']}\desktop\file.json"

class Class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 100

def save(filename, age):
    with open(filename,'w') as f_object:
        a = {}
        a["users"] = {"Jack": {"age": age}}
        json.dump(a, f_object, indent=4)


while True:
    var = input("1-new, 2-save, 3-load, 4-save_def, 5-quit: ")
    if var == "1":
        instance = Class()

    elif var == "2":
        with open(filename,'w') as f_object:
            a = {}
            a["users"] = {"Jack": {"age": instance.age,}}
            json.dump(a, f_object, indent=4)

    elif var == "3":
        with open(filename) as f_obj:
            save = json.load(f_obj)
        age = save["users"]["Jack"]["age"]
        instance = Class()
        instance.age = age

    elif var == "4":
        save(filename, instance.age)

    elif var == "5":
        quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке `save = json.load(f_obj)` вы заменяете функцию `save` словарём.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо переименовать или функцию

```
def save(filename, age):
```

или переменную `save` в `save = json.load(f_obj)`.